# BlueJ is not working

Tags: ide

I'm new to Ubuntu. I had installed JDK 7 but still BlueJ is not working. I need help as I need BlueJ for my school activities and Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the /usr/bin/bluej script file.  Java 7 is now called java-7-oracle instead of java-7-sun.  Or alternatively just use the openjdk-7 version in the repository.  Near as I can tell java-6 is still - sun .....but for how long?